# Android Java Activity displays which Fragment is visible

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I'm learning about Activities and Fragments right now. I have a simple app that changes the Fragment view whenever I click on a button. I've also noticed that I can swipe between different Fragments.

In my Activity, when I click on a button, I have a TextView that will display which Fragment I'm in. When I swipe between activities, I'd also like the Activity's TextView to display which Fragment I'm in.

For instance, when I click btn2 in my Activity, TextView will display "you're in tab2". When I swipe to the next fragment, I'd like my Activity to display something like "you're in tab3" based on which fragment is being viewed.

I'm already using OnDataPass to do stuff from when a user submits info inside the Fragment. What's another way I can pass data over from when the user swipes to a different Fragment to let the Activity know what to display in my TextView? Or would I continue using OnDataPass?

Here's my Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

    mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);
}


public void onClickBtn1(View v){
    int gotoIndex = 0;
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(gotoIndex, true);
    textView.setText("you're in tab1");
}

public void onClickBtn2(View v){
    int gotoIndex = 1;
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(gotoIndex, true);
    textView.setText("you're in tab2");
}

public void onClickBtn3(View v){
    int gotoIndex = 2;
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(gotoIndex, true);
    textView.setText("you're in tab3");
}

public void onClickBtn4(View v){
    Main2Activity.fromActivity("abc");
    Log.i("btn4", "was clicked");
}

//used for when fragment passes data to activity
@Override
public void onDataPass(String data) {
    Log.d("LOG", "passed data: " + data);
}



private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new Main2Activity(), "TAB1");
    adapter.addFragment(new Main3Activity(), "TAB2");
    adapter.addFragment(new Main4Activity(), "TAB3");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of tasks you should use `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

    mSectionsPageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // Here you get a new position.
                textView.setText("you're in tab" + String.valueOf(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    setupViewPager(mViewPager);
}
```